# ASP.NET MVC - Check Initiator in Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Apologies if this has been answered.

I am trying to determine if the initiator of an action is "click" or "navigate"; ie whether the user physically clicked a link or typed/edited a url.

Is there anything in the request I can use in an Action Filter, or is this client side only. I am using debugging tools and I can see the initiator there.

I only want a user to be able to access an Action where they have clicked on a link, rather than type the url directly and then I can redirect to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiator column in debugging tools cannot be passed to the server side, it is just debugging information, provided by browser.

You can use Request.UrlReferrer to determine if user came from another page (url referer is not null), or navigate (url referer is null)

Action filter attribute will look like that:

```
public class IsRequestFromSameDomainAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null )
        {
            //do something
        }
        else 
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the built-in anti forgery token. It works by writing a value out to the form on the client side, and has a cookie for the same state that's compared server side. If they don't match, the request fails.

So, in the view,

```
<script>
    function submit(e) {
      if (e.target.className.match(/submit/)) { 
        e.target.form.submit();
      }
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('click', submit);
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("url", "protected")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a class="submit" href="/protected/url">Link</a>
}
```

And the action method only needs the associated attributes,

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Url()
{
}
```

Comment: OP is asking about making a GET (either via the address bar or clicking a link) - not a POST.

Comment: "make sure a request comes from clicking my link" (paraphrase) seems a natural fit for the anti forgery token. Do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: See the answer from Victor Leontyev :)

Comment: Referrer can be spoofed easily. If that doesn't matter, then Victor's is likely a better idea because it's simple.

Comment: All, thanks for all your comments. I should have said that this is not for security purposes, I have a whole host of other checks for that. The idea was to try and prevent users trying to change the query string "where the change is actually to a page they are permitted to view" - Students tend to want to "play" and so I just want to send a "strongly worded message" not to !!!!